# Why there isn't any law resulting from the Algorithmic Accountability Act of 2019?

Tags: united-states, legal-research, congress

It was stated that no later than 2 years, law must be created according to this bill. I can't find the law anywhere.

Talking about this bill:
[H.R.2231 - Algorithmic Accountability Act of 2019](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/2231/actions)

Comment: A "bill" means a proposed law that has not been adopted by Congress. The use of the term "Act" in a bill is aspirational and reflects that language that it would have if passed as a law.

Answer (score 7):

The bill was never passed.

According to the [list of all actions on Congress.gov](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/2231/all-actions), the bill was referred to the Subcommittee on Consumer Protection and Commerce in April 2019. Evidently, that subcommittee never did anything further with it. The bill was never voted on by either the House or the Senate.